# reading and writing data as BigInteger datatype numbers from a file in java

Tags: java, file-io, rsa, biginteger

I was coding the RSA algorithm with 2048 bit keys in JAVA. The keys generated are stored as BigIntegers datatype.

```
    int x=in.read();
    while(x!=-1)
    {
        data[a++] = BigInteger.valueOf(x);
        x=in.read();   
    }
```

This piece of code reads the input from a file using FileInputStream class. The BigInteger array data stores the input then exponential modulo operation is performed on it, then it is written to another file in form of byte array.

```
    for(int t=0;t<enc.length;t++)
    {
        out.write(enc[t].toByteArray());
    }
```

The output is the encrypted data. To decrypt it, I need to read the encrypted data from the output file, but on reading the byte stream from the file in form of byte array, I will not get the same BigInteger number to again exponent modulo it, as the code will not know how many bytes are to be clubbed to make the same number which was written. Is there any other method which could write the BigInteger numbers then read it form the file producing the same BigInteger numbers or any other technique to store and retrieve the RSA encrypted data from the file ?

Comment: I think it should work, if you read the file into a byte[] and set this directly to a BigInteger-constructor.

Comment: there will be more than one BigInteger number so byte array will take them all at once and could not produce the same numbers that was written on the file as there will be no delimiter for each number.

Comment: You can read your numbers from the file as `String` and convert them to `BigInteger` using the constructor `BigInteger(String)`

Comment: ok. Save every number in a single line. Than read every line into a byte[] and create for every number a BigInteger with one of the numbers as byte[] in the constructor.

Comment: Perform operations on the `BigInteger` -> write to file as `String` -> read `String` from file -> use `BigInteger(String)` to get back the number

Comment: storing the number in form of string is a good idea but I have to put a delimiter after every number, this will make the encryption a bit less secure, I was thinking if I could get a solution using byte stream input rather than character stream so that it could become easier to perform other encryption algorithm like aes before rsa.

Comment: @UweSchmidt to change a line, a delimiter will be required(e.g '\n'), and while reading as a byte stream from a file, the delimiter cannot be used as successful tool for line change as the delimiter will also have some byte value. Suppose a situation in which a byte in a BigInteger number has same byte value as the delimiter, then the read input will have wrong value.